# DRF queryset to return specific field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a django rest framework application with this structure (assuming imports are correct, so I omit them from the code below.

models.py:

```
class Door(models.Model):
  type = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  color = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

serializers.py:

```
class DoorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Door
    fields = ['type', 'color']
```

views.py:

```
class DoorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = DoorSerializer
  queryset = Door.objects.all()
  def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = Door.objects.all()
    parameter = self.request.query_params.get('type', '')
    if parameter:
      return queryset.filter(type=parameter)
    else:
      return queryset
```

So far this behaves as intended, when I make an api call to `localhost/Doors` it lists all the doors. And when I make an api call to `localhost/Doors/?type=big` it lists all the doors that have the value "big" in their "type" field.

The addition I would like to make is another parameter check which would return a list of all the unique door types that exist in the database. This can be achieved in the manage.py shell by using: `Door.objects.all().values('type').distinct()`

My attempt was the following modifications to views.py:

```
...
parameter = self.request.query.params.get('type', '')
unique = self.request.query.params.get('unique', '')
if parameter:
  ...
elif unique:
  return Door.objects.all().values('type').distinct()
...
```

My assumption was that this would return the same as `Door.objects.all().values('type').distinct()` when I make a call to `localhost/Doors/?unique=whatever`

However I am getting the error: "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `color` on serializer `DoorSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'color'."

I assume this means that the serializer expects an object or a list of objects that contains all the fields of the corresponding model.

Is there some way I could circumvent this by fixing the view or should I create a different serializer? In either case, since I've gotten pretty confused with DRF / django differences and it is possible I won't be able to follow abstract instructions, could you provide a code solution that addresses the issue?  Also, in the very likely case that my assumption is completely off, could you also explain what is causing the problem? Thank you for your time!

Edit for clarifying the desired result:

Assuming my database has 4 doors which are:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "type": "big",
  "color": "blue"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "type": "big",
  "color": "yellow"
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "type": "small",
  "color": "green"
},
{
  "id": 4,
  "type": "big",
  "color": "red"
},
```

I would like to make a `get` request to some url, for instance `localhost/Doors/?unique=Yes` and have the api return to me the list `{"big", "small}`

Comment: If I am able to understand properly, if you are getting unique query parameter, you want to return the list of all possible value ?

Comment: That is correct, all the possible values of a specific variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **WRITING YOUR OWN VIEW:** Short view that returns the list of type. You need to set up a new path here. I'd personally go for this option as the response you expect is way different to what the rest of your view does.

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view()
def Unique_door_types(request):
   types = Door.objects.values_list('type', flat=True).distinct()
   return Response({"types": list(types)})
```

2. **WITHOUT AN ADDITIONAL VIEW:**

No need for additional view or serializer. Override the `list` method. Note that this is closer to a trick than to a good way of programming.

```py
from rest_framework.response import Response

class DoorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DoorSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Door.objects.all()
        parameter = self.request.query_params.get('type', '')
        if parameter:
            return queryset.filter(type=parameter)
        else:
            return queryset

    def list(self, request):
        unique = self.request.query_params.get('unique', '')
        if unique:
            types = Door.objects.values_list('type', flat=True).distinct()
            return Response({"types": list(types)})
        return super().list()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm afraid I can't understand how this code functions and simply adding it to my app doesn't work. I'm updating my question for clarity, in case I have been misunderstood

Comment: A short code on how to make a simple function view to do that would be perfect, and exactly what I need if you could provide. Thanks for answering regardless!

Comment: I have edited with two propositions. The second one is probably closer to what you expect as it does not require an additional view and thus no additional path. It checks whether the unique keywork is there and if so send a custom response.

Comment: Both are absolutely perfect, they work and do exactly what I want! Thank you very much for taking the time to help me :)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to create a separate route like `/doors/types/`. You do this by adding a method to your `DoorViewSet` class with a `@action` decorator. See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing for more details about how to do this.

Comment: I have received a satisfactory solution and am able to proceed with my project. Your answer is relevant and correct though, thank you for answering :)